One player rotate the other one also rotate in unity photon pun
So i am making a 2d multiplayer platformer shooter. I have ran into a problem that is that when i rotate the mouse on one player, the other player also rotate.
this.mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > nextTimeToFire)
{

    GameObject bullet1 = Instantiate(bullet, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
    Rigidbody2D rb2 = bullet1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb2.AddForce(firepoint.right * 50f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    ScreenManager.Instance.ScreenShake(10f, 0.1f);
    Destroy(bullet1, 20f);
    nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f/fireRate;


}
Vector2 lookDir = this.mousePos - rb1.position;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, angle);

It only happens when my cursor is near the other player so I suspect it has something to do with cam.screentoworldpoint. How do I make it so that the rotation only applies to the local player.

Please read [mcve] as this code alone does not give context or otherwise.

pretty sure you forgot to disable this script/method in case it is the instance of the remote client ... PhotonView.IsMine
